# Plsease expain following python codes

Tags: python

Why x value is updating along with y, how it works any one please expain this code

```
x = ['foo', [1,2,3], 10.4]
y = list(x)
y[0] = 'fooooooo'
y[1][0] = 4
print x
print y

Output 
['foo', [4, 2, 3], 10.4]
['fooooooo', [4, 2, 3], 10.4]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[1,2,3]` is a nested list within list `x`. The code

```
y = list(x)
```

binds to `y` a shallow copy of list `x`, but the nested list remains the same. So updating the nested list via `y` affects the same list referenced in `x`.

You can check this by using `is`:

```
>>> x = ['foo', [1,2,3], 10.4]
>>> y = list(x)
>>> x is y
False
>>> x[1] is y[1]
True
```

So `x[1]` and `y[1]` are the same object.

You can use `copy.deepcopy()` to make a complete copy of the list and it's nested elements:

```
>>> from copy import deepcopy
>>> x = ['foo', [1,2,3], 10.4]
>>> y = deepcopy(x)
>>> x is y
False
>>> x[1] is y[1]
False
>>> y[0] = 'fooooooo'
>>> y[1][0] = 4
>>> x
['foo', [1, 2, 3], 10.4]
>>> y
['fooooooo', [4, 2, 3], 10.4]
```

which shows that a new instance of nested list has been copied into `y` and that each nested list is independent of the other.

Answer (score 1):

You make `y` a shallow copy of `x` which means that the member lists of `y` will be the same lists as in `x`:

```
>>> l = [1, 2, 3]
>>> x = ["foo", l, 10.4]
>>> y = list(x)
>>> y[1] is l
True
>>> x[1] is l
True
```

You can use `copy.deepcopy` to make y a deep copy of x that won't share internal references:

```
>>> import copy
>>> y = copy.deepcopy(x)
>>> y[1] is l
False
>>> y[1][0] = 5
>>> y
['foo', [5, 2, 3], 10.4]
>>> l
[1, 2, 3]
>>> x
['foo', [1, 2, 3], 10.4]
```

Answer (score 1):

I have gone through the different copy methods, the followiing output will give a brief description, how it works

```
x = ['foo', [1,2,3], 10.4]
y = list(x) //copy.copy(x) // copy.deepcopy(x) // y = x
y[0] = 'fooooo'
y[1][0] = 4
print x
print y

Output 
deep copy ['foo', [1, 2, 3], 10.4]
          ['fooooo', [4, 2, 3], 10.4]

copy      ['foo', [4, 2, 3], 10.4]
          ['fooooo', [4, 2, 3], 10.4]

list(x)   ['foo', [4, 2, 3], 10.4]
          ['fooooo', [4, 2, 3], 10.4]
```

when y = x ['foo', [4, 2, 3], 10.4]
              ['fooooo', [4, 2, 3], 10.4]

Answer (score 0):

Because the inner list `[1, 2, 3]` is being 'copied' by reference, not value, when you initialise `y`. Hence any changes to it within one of `x` or `y` are reflected in the other.

You can use [deepcopy](https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy) to get the behaviour you want:

```
from copy import deepcopy
x = ['foo', [1,2,3], 10.4]
y = deepcopy(x)
y[0] = 'fooooooo'
y[1][0] = 4
print x
print y
```

Output:

```
['foo', [1, 2, 3], 10.4]
['fooooooo', [4, 2, 3], 10.4]
```